# How to decode bytes from ByteBuffer to UTF-8 symbols in NIO?

Tags: java, utf-8, file-io, decode, nio

I need to read and print some text from the file using NIO. Code works fine with English, but for Russian I need to decode bytes in UTF-8.
I don't understand the order for converting bytes to UTF-8 symbols. Can you help?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (FileChannel fChan = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get("D:/test.txt"))) {

         ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
         int count;

            do {
                count = fChan.read(byteBuf);
                
                if(count != -1) {
                    byteBuf.rewind();

                    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        System.out.print((char) byteBuf.get());
                    }
                }
            } while(count != -1);

         } catch(InvalidPathException e) {
             System.out.println("Path exception " + e);
         } catch(IOException e) {
             System.out.println("IO Exception " + e);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To read UTF-8 encoded text from a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), you can decode it as a [`CharBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html):

```java
CharBuffer charBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(byteBuffer);
```

For more fine-grained access, use the underlying [`CharsetDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html):

```java
CharsetDecoder charsetDecoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();
```

If you truly want to take the raw bytes yourself and decode that using UTF-8, then you first need to learn how UTF-8 works, so do a web search for UTF-8 and start reading, because the way the question is written, it sounds like you don't know that yet. To actually write code for that, you also need to know how to do bit-manipulation in Java, so if you don't know that either, do another web search and start reading. If you can't out that information together to do it, write a new question, explain what you do know, and what is stopping you from applying what you know to the problem.

Comment: Andreas, I do understand how UTF-8 works, but I don't need my own low-level code for decoding. I just wanted to know if there are ways to decode this by classes and methods from standard Java library.

Comment: @vasseugs That is so not what the question is asking, because it says you don't understand how to convert UTF-8 encoded bytes into text *(though you phrased it differently, in a weird way)*, which would indicate that you don't understand UTF-8, but the answer is yes, as you can see in this answer.